# Windows DVD Maker on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, dvd, mpeg

Something I really miss in Windows 8 is the [Windows DVD Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Burn-a-DVD-Video-disc-with-Windows-DVD-Maker).

I tried to get it running on Windows 8 by copying the DVD Maker directory from Windows 7 over to Windows 8.  When I run it, I get the following error:

[image: MPEG-2 encoder is missing]

I had hoped that this could be resolved by installing the Media Center add-on for Windows 8, but that did not have any effect.

Several forum posts have suggested installing a codec pack such as the [K-Lite codec pack](http://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm), but I have always had bad experiences with those.  I did, however, try to install the [Shark007 codec pack](http://shark007.net/), but that didn't work either.

I also tried running the following commands (which did complete successfully, mind you) in an elevated command prompt, but they didn't change the outcome.

```
regsvr32 msmpeg2vdec.dll
regsvr32 msmpeg2adec.dll
regsvr32 msmpeg2enc.dll
```

I know there are other DVD making programs out there, some are even free, but the few I have tried do not compare to Windows DVD Maker's simplicity and beauty.  Is there any way to make it work on Windows 8?

Comment: K-Lite is safe to use and install.

Comment: OP did not say it was not safe, just a bad experience. most people have issues because they install more than one codec pack, you can only have one installed at a time, if you want to try a different one uninstall the old one first.

Comment: The SDK does not work either. Someone try to run Process Explorer on a working Windows 7 machine with DVD Maker and see what it uses to "fire up".
The Media Center Install only gets you the DECODER, we are missing the ENCODER.
Looks like the original OP already tried the Shark codecs, and it was a no go.
I really used the Windows DVD Maker a lot, this is the first thing I have not liked about W8.
The start button was easily replaced by the sourceforge project Classic Start menu 3.6.2.

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to use a third party codec and/or use a different DvD maker. On the codec pack, did you use the Win8 version? http://shark007.net/win8codecs.html

Scott Hanselman had that as a chief complaint a bit ago.
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCreateADVDOnWindows8EvenThoughWindowsDVDMakerIsGoneDVDStyler.aspx

Due to license fees Microsoft removed MPEG-2 from Windows 8, but they are available as feature packs in either Win 8 Pro, or in the Media Player feature pack. For right now, the Media Feature pack is free, and should get you going:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/feature-packs

If you want to go the 'hard' way using Microsoft components, there is still the MPEG-2 decoder as part of the Windows 8 SDK and the Media Foundation. So, you could download the SDK from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904949 and you should have the necessary DLLs registered (I have not validated this method yet; I'll check it out this evening unless you beat me to it).

Comment: I've got the Media Feature pack, no change.  I also tried registering the DLLs, no change.  Question updated to state this.

Comment: From the cmd prompt try sfc /scannow

Comment: @Louis You mean this one, right?  This is what I have: http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows-8/feature-packs

Comment: While MS have not exactly been forthcoming, in actuality, the Media Center Feature Pack **ONLY** provides Media Center and MPEG-2 support **for** Media Center.  For example, Media Player can not play DVDs in Windows 8 even with the Media Center Feature Pack.  Also, Movie Maker (part of Windows Essentials) supports DVD-burning in Windows 7, but not in Windows 8 (tested just now).

Answer (score 3):

After using the codec packs I'm not able to run the Windows DVD Maker on Windows 8. I think it due to not any support of MPEG-2 codecs in Windows 8 for Windows DVD Maker.

So if you want to use the simple tool as like Windows DVD Maker then I think you should have to give a try [DVDStyler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/) which is a free one.

**Feature are listed on official site are**:

> create and burn DVD video with interactive menus
>   design your own DVD menu or select one from the list of ready to use menu templates v1.8.0
>   create photo slideshow
>   add multiple subtitle and audio tracks
>   support of AVI, MOV, MP4, MPEG, OGG, WMV and other file formats
>   support of MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DivX, Xvid, MP2, MP3, AC-3 and other audio and video formats
>   support of multi-core processor
>   use MPEG and VOB files without reencoding
>   put files with different audio/video format on one DVD (support of titleset)
>   user-friendly interface with support of drag & drop
>   flexible menu creation on the basis of scalable vector graphic
>   import of image file for background
>   place buttons, text, images and other graphic objects anywhere on the menu screen
>   change the font/color and other parameters of buttons and graphic objects
>   scale any button or graphic object
>   copy any menu object or whole menu
>   customize navigation using DVD scripting

It has a very simple user interface which will let you choose easily what you want.

[image]

Here you can set a menu for your DVD playback.  You can change interface settings under **Configuration>Settings**.

[image]

You can set the properties for the DVD under **DVD>options...**

[image]

You can set here Disc label, Video Quality, aspect ratio, audio format etc.

You can save a project to burn it later and then open it under **File** menu. You have different option to add the DVD under **DVD>add** menu

> File
>   File as chapter 
>   Titles from DVD
>   Menu
>   vmMenu
>   Tileset

[image]

**Edit**: After a lots of Googling I found myself helpless to run the Windows DVD Maker. And I reached on a conclusion that Microsoft has withdrawn the support of MPEG-2 encoders without media center. Now question arises **why third party codec doesn't work**?

**Reason according to me**: If third party encoder/decoder will support the media feature of Microsoft is providing then who will buy the media center. VLC and other third party players have inbuilt encoder/decoder to run the files. So Microsoft is making a mess with this thing. You have to live with it until someone don't find the hack for this.

Comment: Check out the edits dude.